# Closest lower-bound on the prime counting function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The title says it all: what is the closest proven lower-bound on the prime counting function?

Note that I'm not limiting this to continuous functions. If a lower-bound on the prime-counting function exists over any infinite domain and is consistently closer than a continuous contemporary, I'm interested in the discrete function.

Comment: Are you looking for a lower bound on $\pi(x)$ for all $x$ or just one that works for large enough $x$?

Comment: Large enough x is fine, even for very large x, so long as the function is among the closest known.

Comment: Well $\frac{x}{\log(x)-1}<\pi(x)$ is a pretty good one - probably not the closest, but still pretty close and easy to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest lower bound on $\pi(x)$ depends upon the minimum value of $x$ that you are talking about because, as $x$ increases, the best known estimate for the lower bound becomes sharper and sharper. Example

For $x \ge 11$ we have

$$
\pi(x) \ge \frac{x}{\ln x}. 
$$

For $x \ge 5393$ we have

$$
\pi(x) \ge \frac{x}{\ln x - 1}. 
$$

For $x \ge 88783$ we have

$$
\pi(x) \ge \frac{x}{\ln x} \Big(1 + \frac{1}{\ln x} + \frac{2}{\ln^2 x}\Big).
$$

In general for any given $x$ it is possible to find the lower bound on $\pi(x)$ and so very few number theorist are interested in finding such explicit bounds because there is no end to it and such bounds do not provide as much information as an asymptotic formula anyways.